# How to pass a data from an existing razor view as the parameter into a controller to load the new razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to asp.net mvc, I have my main razor page Index with a button Edit Assessment and I don't know how to pass whatever id which my Index page have.

Right now I am passing a default value id = "2" as my parameter but this shouldn't be as the Index may contain any id depending on the selected record

Here is my code snippet from my Index page

```
<form asp-controller="Assessments" asp-action="Index" method="get">
<p>
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg float-right" 
value="Edit Assessment" 
onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("EditAssessment", "Assessments", new 
{ id = "2" })'" /> 
</p>
</form>

....
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            ID
        </th>
....
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
<tr>
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
</td>
....
</tr>
}
</tbody>
</table>
```

I would like to update the id = "2" into id = "Id from my model"

Comment: Are you using a viewmodel on this page? From the code above I am presuming that this view model is a list of IDs?

Comment: Hi JamesS, it's a list of data belongs to the specific Id.

Answer (score 0):

this is issue has been resolved.

I have updated my controller and added the ViewData["ProfileId"] = id;

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(
        int? id, 
        int? pageNumber,
        int pageSize)
    {
        ...some codes here

        var dataDividendToolContext = _context.Assessment
            .Include(a => a.AsIs)
            .Include(a => a.Profile)
            .Include(a => a.Question)
            .Include(a => a.Vision)
            .Where(a => a.ProfileId == id);

        ...some codes here

        ViewData["ProfileId"] = id;

        ...some codes here

    }
```

On my CSHTML button I passed the ViewData["ProfileId"] as my parameter as seen below.

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg float-right" value="Edit 
Assessment" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("EditAssessment", "Assessments", new 
{ id = ViewData["ProfileId"] })'" />
```